# What's the correct way to loop over a list and make a dictionary with dict comprehension in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

`testWords` is a list with words. `setTestWords` is the same list as a set. I want to create a dictionary with Dict Comprehension where I will use the word as key and the count as value. I'm also using the .count.

Example output would be like this:

```
>>> dictTestWordsCount[:2]
>>> {'hi': 22, 'hello': 99}
```

This is the line if code I'm using but it seems to crash my notebook every time.

```
l = {x: testWords.count(x) for x in setTestwords}
```

Comment: `collections.Counter(testWords)`

Comment: It's for an assignment and I clearly told how I wanted to solve the problem: with .count and dict comprehension.

Comment: what's the error you get?  or does it just take a long time to run?

Comment: What is `dictTestWordsCount[:2]`? Slicing a dict?

Comment: Yup, takes too long a time to load. But would it be the proper code or am I missing something here.

Comment: and the slide was just to show example output here in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what causes your notebook to crash...

```
In [62]: txt = "the quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog"

In [63]: testWords = txt.split()

In [64]: setTestWords = set(testWords)

In [65]: {x:testWords.count(x) for x in setTestWords}
Out[65]:
{'brown': 1,
 'dog': 1,
 'fox': 1,
 'jumped': 1,
 'lazy': 1,
 'over': 1,
 'quick': 1,
 'red': 1,
 'the': 2}
```

---

Or better, Use `collection.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

for word in txt.split():
    d[word]+=1

print(d)
defaultdict(int,
            {'brown': 1,
             'dog': 1,
             'fox': 1,
             'jumped': 1,
             'lazy': 1,
             'over': 1,
             'quick': 1,
             'red': 1,
             'the': 2})
```